# Making a filter searchable on the page of post list at Wordpress backend

Tags: dropdown

I have a dropdown menu of all authors or usernames on the page of post table or post list. I would like to make that dropdown menu searchable. Here are my codes:

```
    <?php

    // Get an array of WP usernames:
    $users = get_users();
    $user_names = wp_list_pluck( $users, 'user_login' );

    ?>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var usernamesArray = <?php echo json_encode($user_names); ?>;  // Convert php array into jQuery array
        $("#author").select2({
          data: usernamesArray
        });
      });
    </script>
```

The above codes work somewhat and slow. After refreshing the page, it becomes blank.

What is the right way of maker a filter searchable at WP backend?

Many thanks in advance.

Here are custom codes in functions.php for adding Author filter:

```
  function rudr_filter_by_the_author() {
    $params = array(
      'name' => 'author', // this is the "name" attribute for filter <select>
      'show' => 'user_login',
      'orderby' => 'user_login',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'show_option_all' => 'All Authors' // label for all authors (display posts without filter)
    );
   
    if ( isset($_GET['user']) )
      $params['selected'] = $_GET['user']; // choose selected user by $_GET variable
   
    wp_dropdown_users( $params ); // print the ready author list
  }
  add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'rudr_filter_by_the_author');
```

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

here are some notes:

1. It's important to enqueue scripts and styles properly in WordPress. You should enqueue the Select2 script and its styles using the WordPress enqueue system. This ensures that they are loaded correctly and in the right order.
2. Use WordPress AJAX for Dynamic Data Loading: If the list of users is large, loading all usernames at once can be slow and resource-intensive. To improve performance, you can use WordPress AJAX to load usernames dynamically as the user types in the search box.
3. Add this code to your themes functions.php file

```
// Enqueue scripts and styles
function wpb_enqueue_scripts_author_dropdown() {
    wp_enqueue_style('select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('author-dropdown-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/js/author-dropdown.js', array('jquery', 'select2'), mt_rand(00000, 9999999), true);

    wp_localize_script('author-dropdown-script', 'wpb_author_dropdown', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    ));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_enqueue_scripts_author_dropdown');

// AJAX handler for fetching usernames
function wpb_ajax_fetch_usernames() {
    $search_term = isset($_GET['q']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['q']) : '';
    $users = get_users(array('search' => '*' . esc_attr($search_term) . '*'));
    $user_names = wp_list_pluck($users, 'user_login');
    wp_send_json($user_names);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_fetch_usernames', 'wpb_ajax_fetch_usernames');

// Create a shortcode for the dropdown
function wpb_author_dropdown_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <select id="author" style="width: 50%"></select>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('wpb_author_dropdown', 'wpb_author_dropdown_shortcode');
```

Now you can call your html by using the shortcode [wpb_author_dropdown] in a text editor or code box, or, you can use the do_shortcode function in a php file like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpb_author_dropdown]'); ?>
```

OR

```
echo do_shortcode('[wpb_author_dropdown]');
```

Now, in your theme directory create this file:
/includes/js/author-dropdown.js
In that add this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#author").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: wpb_author_dropdown.ajax_url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    action: 'fetch_usernames',
                    q: params.term // search term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item,
                            id: item
                        };
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: WordPress Buddha, Great work. I dont have a file to use short code - it is WP Admin backend for a custom post type; I created that author filter usings some codes in functions.php. Is it possible to use just custom codes in functions.php and a file in /js folder you advised? I basically created a PHP file in /php folder and include 'php/file.php'; in functions. But the crash or slow happens because of jQuery as you mentioned. Many thanks

Comment: You can use the code anyway you like, does not have to be like I used it above, a plain php file works as well.

Comment: Hi WordPress Buddha
I could not get your codes working with custom Author filter or dropdown menu created in functions.php. Please check those codes in my updated post above. Cheers

Comment: What page are you trying to add the dropdown to? Please give me a few more details so I can possibly reproduce the issue you are having

Comment: it is the page of post table at WP Admin backend. My website uses CPT created by a Theme. There was no Author filter there; I added it using the above custom codes in functions.php. I checked the file path to js file is correct; there is no error with your codes, but no search box is shown - they dont work.

Comment: @WordPressBuddha Can you please pay closer attention to the questions you're answering. This is the second time I've seen you provide code for a shortcode even though it has nothing to do with the question that was asked.